# InterfaceBuilder going landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a XIB in interface builder that is in Portrait mode and has 5 UILabels on it spaced evenly across the view. When the iPhone is rotated right or left I want the labels to spread evenly across the view to take full advantage of the extra screen width.

I can do this with one control really easily using the Size&Position bit of Interface Builder but how do I set up the other controls to do this?

Is this something you have to do programmatically?

Thanks

Mike
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and do it by setting the autoresizingMask property that [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) has. This would be the easiest way, if you can get it to do what you want. You can set this wherever you create or initialize your views:

`view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;`

It's possible that you won't be able to get the exact positioning for all 5 of your labels this way; but you should definitely be able to use it for at least some of them. For the rest, you want to implement the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. This will get called whenever the iPad rotates, and you can set up the location of your labels inside that method.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work.  I have attached a screen shot from IB to help you explain it to me better.

Comment: It isn't related to IB at all. In the code, you have your UIViewController class that controls the view. In this class, you want to implement the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. From inside that method, you can set your labels to be wherever you want them to be. If you don't have pointers to your labels in your controller, you can declare them in your class as IBOutlets and connect them to the labels created in IB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the controls are positioned around the xib, in most case you should be able to avoid coding using the properties displayed under "Autosizing" in interface builder. Basically everything you do here could be done in code using

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing<and the various masks here>
```

don't forget to implement the viewDidLoad method in a way that tells the view to reposition the elements

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

also, a useful bit is that on ipad, embedding viewcontrollers inside a navigationcontroller makes the ipad handle the most part of rotation and resizing issues.